# Initial Yaw Maneuver: Lean into or away from tower?

Tags: launch

Some rockets do an initial yaw maneuver to help avoid contact with the tower.

I know the yaw is in the plane of the tower: the rocket either leans into or away from the tower... But which of these is it? I've been figuring it leans away (so the nose moves back from the tower while the tail end moves closer), but I have a feeling I might be wrong on this.

Can someone clarify?

Thanks!

Comment: Related (with video) https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23730/6944

Answer (score 5):

Nose away from tower, so tail moves slightly closer to, as seen in [this video of the Antares ORB-2 launch](https://youtu.be/PZKs1Wsy7aE?t=1777).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, @RussellBorogove!

Comment: Oh wow, that is a very noticeable yaw, and it does its job of pushing the rocket out from the tower. OK, now I know what a yaw maneuver looks like :D